# Do Freon gas leaks occur in Airplane conditioning systems as well?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

I was just reading about [Aircraft Conditiong Systems](http://www.energyquest.ca.gov/how_it_works/air_conditioner.html) and found that, the A.C. mechanism begins with compressor in the engine. Do these compressor also work the way in which AC/Refrigerator's compressor do? If they do, then [Freon Gas Leaks](http://aetinc.biz/newsletters/august-2009) should be something happening atleast once in a long period .. They are pretty common with household Air conditioning system.So, does this happens? I have never really heard of something like this happening to an aircraft..

Comment: there is no freon on board of an aircraft. related: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5031 http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8535

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Large aircraft use [air conditioning packs (air-cycle machines)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_cycle_machine) which uses only air, compressors and heat exchangers to cool/heat the air. There is no freon involved.

Comment: Just read the link. Sent me wondering on the totally off-topic though of "why don't we use these in cars?". Yes, this is OT, no, I don't expect anyone to address it - just thinking out loud.

Comment: @FreeMan: The air-to-air heat exchanger works the same way as our freon/ammonia air conditioner - it's a heat pump. We use freon to miniaturize the heat pump.

Comment: @FreeMan With [a few notable exceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysler_Turbine_Car) we don't generally have turbine-powered cars with a compressor section to bleed air from, nor a nice cold environment to dump waste heat to (when you want air conditioning to cool your car it's usually hot out), so an air-cycle machine isn't as attractive in a car as it is in a jet up in the flight levels (with sub-freezing air to cool the bleed air to whatever reasonable temperature you desire):)

Answer (score 1):

While transport-category jets [tend to use air-cycle machines like ratchet freak mentioned](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/15081) some light airplanes are available with "standard" (freon heat-pump) air conditioners.
These have the same refrigerant-leak problems as your typical car air conditioner as seals age, pipes crack, etc.

These air conditioners are also not particularly popular accessories because they add weight and mechanical complexity to the aircraft (I don't think I've ever seen a plane with one installed in person, though I know a few folks over on the Piper forums who have the factory air conditioning in their planes).