# How does air conditioning work on a commercial airliner?

Tags: commercial-aviation

I know a lot about airplanes, but I've always wondered the vents deal with air pressure in the sky

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8535/755) explain that in quite a bit of detail.

Answer (score 5):

Came across this diagram that sums it up pretty nicely:

[image]

- You get 'bleed' air from the engine compressor stage. On 'bleedless' aircraft, such as the B787, this is done by electric compressors instead.
- Air temperature and pressure is adjusted as necessary in the conditioning packs since it heated up a lot when it was compressed.
- Air is then distributed to the different 'zones'. A bit of the cabin air is recirculated.
- Some areas, such as the cockpit, generally receive air directly from the packs without recirculating at a slightly higher pressure, to blow possible smoke away from the interior and to prevent smoke being recirculated into the cockpit. For the same reason, you try create a flow out through the baggage hold.

Here is a more complicated diagram from avsoft's website for a CRJ200:

[image: crj200]