# Can heated air be provided in the cabin in commercial airlines?

Tags: cabin-design, temperature

Having travelled quite a number of times, there are times, when the cabin becomes a bit too cold, or people with certain condition get shivering quickly. In such circumstances and generally, is it possible to request for heated air in the cabin. If not the entire cabin, but atleast to specified seats, via the air flow controller on top of the head.

Before that, are airlines equipped to provide heated air, like in a car?

Comment: related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/17641/1467 (see also the linked questions)

Comment: _Can_ it be provided? Yes, sure. _Is_ it provided? Not that I'm aware of. Generally, the cabin will heat up pretty quickly with all those self-propelled heaters moving around, and needs to be cooled. There are, of course, those who are _always_ cold (like my mother), and for them, the airlines usually provide blankets.

Comment: Oh, and the smart ones (like my mother) wear lots of clothes _knowing_ they'll be cold. Seriously, she wears ski pants to fly in so she'll stay warm. Actually, she wears ski pants nearly all year round so she can stay warm...

Comment: Even all those people in the cabin together are not enough to heat it up when the outside temperature is -52°C. So yes, heat is provided, but I do notice in general they keep the temperature at the lower end of being comfortable. Too cold for many

Answer (score 8):

The fresh air vents near your head at each seat can not be adjusted for temperature individually.  Cabin temperature is controlled. Just ask a Flight Attendant to warm it up as they have a control panel to adjust cabin temperature by zone.

Most modern airliners use bleed air from the engines to power two Air Conditioning Packs which circulate cooled or heated air throughout the cabin.

[Environmental control system (aircraft)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environmental_control_system_(aircraft))

B777 Air Systems

[image]

Comment: 20C? No wonder it's so cold! (for reference, the temperature recommended by the government here is 25.5C)

Comment: 25.5C (78F)?  That's napping weather right there! You heat the interior of a plane to 25C, then fill it with passengers, it's going from springtime warm to summer time hot in 30-45 minutes!

Comment: Except that if you ask the flight attendant to warm it up, I'll probably ask to have the heat turned down :-)  After all, as noted above, people who are cold can always ask for blankets or wear warmer clothes, while overheated people taking off clothing could be considered socially unacceptable.

Comment: @FreeMan I think I'd still prefer 25.5C over 20C (68F,) though, particularly while sitting down inside. I seem to recall reading from Korean Air that they keep their cabins somewhere in the upper 70s during flight, but they operate mostly long-haul flights where people want to sleep anyway, so sleeping conditions aren't a bad thing there.

Comment: The UK legal minimum limit for *office* temperatures is 16C (61F) and the recommended temp is 20C. There is no legal maximum (the recommended maximum is 30C), but if the temp in my office was stuck on 25C I would be complaining that it was too hot. 20C or 21C is about right by UK standards.

Comment: So what is the legal minimum and maximum temperatures allowed in an aircraft,  say in US and UK?

Comment: I am not aware of any legal minimum. The default position at Auto commands 23 degrees and that is where I generally leave it for both the flight deck and cabin.